# How to configure pylint in the python source

Tags: python, suppress-warnings, pylint

Is it possible to disable certain pylint errors/warnings in the python source code itself ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The #pylint: disable syntax mentionned by @kalgasnik is the correct one. You can find more information about this in the [Pylint FAQ](http://docs.pylint.org/message-control) (your question is `meth2`)

Comment: Correct link to FAQ: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-message-for-a-particular-module-only

Comment: Why is an answer referencing the correct answer in the same question the one marked correct, instead of the correct answer?

Answer (score 13):

```
def foo():
    print "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
print "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

pylint output:

```
C:  2: Line too long (87/80)
C:  3: Line too long (83/80)
C:  1: Missing docstring
C:  1:foo: Black listed name "foo"
C:  1:foo: Missing docstring
```

Add comment "# pylint: disable=CODE", code for "Line too long" message - C0301:

```
def foo():
    # pylint: disable=C0301
    print "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
print "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

pylint output:

```
I:  2: Locally disabling C0301
C:  4: Line too long (83/80)
C:  1: Missing docstring
C:  1:foo: Black listed name "foo"
C:  1:foo: Missing docstring
```

Answer (score 5):

In the eclipse ide, with pydev, you can put a comment after the line of code, with the format `# IGNORE:_ID_`.  I don't know if this also works in other programs.
For example:

```
import something  # IGNORE:W0611
```

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing in Pylint supporting this comment format. Maybe your IDE supports this to not report the Pylint warning, but this makes it IDE-specific.

Comment: @gurney I am indeed using eclipse with pydev. I never realised that this was an ide specific feature.

Comment: @gurney: Done, I should have thought of editing it immediately after your comment. Butyyou could also have edited it yourself, of course (no offense).